# Entropy of negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, entropy

As you know, the distribution of a negative binomial random variable  $X\sim \text{NB}(r,p)$ is:
$$P(X=k)={k+r-1\choose k}p^k(1-p)^r$$

Well, by using the general definition of entropy we get that the entropy is expressed by a complicated infinite sum containing binomial coefficients and logarithms.

I was wondering if there is some way to simplify the expression.

Comment: [Look at](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06394.pdf) Eq (23) on page 5.